# Ember.js views dealing with existing DOM content

Tags: ember.js

Quite often we deal with lists of things on our site. These initially get loaded with the rest of the page from the server. However, any updates received we would like to update these lists using Ember.

All of the examples I have seen so far with Ember views deal with controlling content on a page that has always been created purely by Ember. What options are there for dealing with DOM elements that already exist on the page with Ember views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been some discussion around this idea here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/563

Comment: Had totally missed that, describes our issue exactly

Answer (score 2):

In the current situation two approaches come to my mind:

- Replace the static rendered list with an Ember.CollectionView as soon as all list items are available to ember as data objects (e.g through ember-data)
- Use plain old jQuery to append the latest updates at the beginning / end of the list

I guess it depends on how complex your list items and the updating logic is. If updates need reordering of items and your list needs complex interaction, the first approach using ember might be better suited, although there could be a "flickering" of content while the lists are replaced. The second approach is much simpler but also limited. I would only use jQuery for appending / prepending content. Still, if the lists are simple it would be overkill to even use ember in this case.